# How to do a ranked search based on number of multiple columns matched

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, string-searching

### Context

I am trying to create a ranked-customer-search that will order results based on "most likely correct". We have several factors we search by, but to keep it simple I will stick with just name, phone number, & email. The goal is that if the customer has an existing account, we use that instead of creating a new account.

It is also worth noting that for this system, a customer account is US state-specific. So it is technically possible for a single person to have 49 existing accounts and still need to have a "new account" created, so there are often many duplicate accounts we can copy information from.

### My Attempt

The query below uses binary values to determine the rank of a result. So a match based on a phone number (0100) scores higher than a match based on name (0001) or email (0010). This works pretty well but isn't quite ideal. For example, an account that matches both email & name will rank lower than an account that matches only a phone number. Unfortunately, this is pretty much my limit when it comes to creating queries. (see [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7591bd/2))

(The `UNION`s below are required because they allow better indexes to be used)

```
SELECT
    results.id,
    SUM(results.score) AS total_score
FROM (
    (
        SELECT
            c1.id,
            4 AS score
        FROM customers c1
        WHERE
            c1.phone = :phone
    ) UNION ALL (
        SELECT
            c2.id,
            2 AS score
        FROM customers c2
        WHERE
            c2.email = :email
    ) UNION ALL (
        SELECT
            c3.id,
            1 AS score
        FROM customers c3
        WHERE
            c3.first_name = :first_name
            AND c3.last_name = :last_name
    )
) results
GROUP BY
    results.id
ORDER BY
    total_score DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

### My Question

I am not sure how to change it so that matching multiple less-important factors ranks higher than a single important factor?

Also, since this is my first time creating a search query like this, there is likely a better and/or more standard way of doing this; so any resources you can share related to this would also be greatly appreciated!

---

Example of the current result set:

| first_name | last_name | phone | email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| john | doe | 5556667777 | johnd@example.com |
| john | doe | 5556667777 |  |
|  |  | 5556667777 |  |
| john | doe |  | johnd@example.com |

Example of the desired result set: (last 2 rows are switched because the last 1 had more matching data)

| first_name | last_name | phone | email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| john | doe | 5556667777 | johnd@example.com |
| john | doe | 5556667777 |  |
| john | doe |  | johnd@example.com |
|  |  | 5556667777 |  |

Comment: Please provide some sample data (as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts, or create online fiddle), criteria values and desired output for this data with detailed explanations.

Comment: @Akina Will do! One moment...

Comment: *I am not sure how to change it so that matching multiple less-important factors ranks higher than a single important factor?* Maybe simply use another values for relative weights? For example, 4,3 and 2? in this case (email+name) will give 5 which is above than single (phone).

Comment: @Akina I added a SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7591bd/2

Comment: Add this link to the question text as an update. Add criteria values and desired output for this fiddle with detailed explanations.

Comment: @Akina They were added!

Comment: See the fiddle by the link in my answer, last query. Relative weights are set to 4-3-2.

Answer (score 2):

In general:

```sql
SELECT *, (  (phone = :phone) * 4
           + (email = :email) * 2
           + (first_name = :first_name AND last_name = :last_name)) AS score
FROM customers
-- HAVING score
ORDER BY score DESC limit 10;
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7591bd/9)